# SVG and JS. Transfer values attribute

Tags: javascript, svg

How to transfer values a from svg attribute stroke-dasharray to tag text class="circle-chart__percent"? This is desirable to do with js, without jquery.

```
<svg class="circle-chart" viewbox="0 0 33.83098862 33.83098862" 
   width="200" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<circle class="circle-chart__background" stroke="#efefef" stroke- 
   width="0.5" fill="none" cx="16.91549431" cy="16.91549431" r="15.91549431" />
<circle class="circle-chart__circle" stroke="#00acc1" stroke-width="0.5" stroke-dasharray="30,100" stroke-linecap="round" fill="none" cx="16.91549431" cy="16.91549431" r="15.91549431" />
<g class="circle-chart__info">
<text class="circle-chart__percent" x="16.91549431" y="15.5" alignment-baseline="central" text-anchor="middle" font-size="8">30%</text>
<text class="circle-chart__subline" x="16.91549431" y="20.5" alignment-baseline="central" text-anchor="middle" font-size="2">Yay 30% progress! 
</text>
</g>
</svg>

<style>
  .circle-chart__circle {
     animation: circle-chart-fill 2s reverse; /* 1 */
     transform: rotate(-90deg); /* 2, 3 */
     transform-origin: center; /* 4 */
   }
   .circle-chart__circle--negative {
     transform: rotate(-90deg) scale(1,-1); /* 1, 2, 3 */
    }
   .circle-chart__info {
     animation: circle-chart-appear 2s forwards;
     opacity: 0;
     transform: translateY(0.3em);
   }
   @keyframes circle-chart-fill {
      to { stroke-dasharray: 0 100; }
   }
   @keyframes circle-chart-appear {
      to {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateY(0);
      }
   }
 </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

In pure JavaScript, you may try this:

```
var svg = document.getElementsByTagName('circle')[1];
var att = svg.getAttribute('stroke-dasharray');
var text = document.querySelector('text.circle-chart__percent');
text.textContent = att;
```

The circle having attribute `stroke-dasharray` is the second circle, so you can get this using `document.getElementsByTagName('circle')[1];` and there is only one element with class `circle-chart__percent` so you can get this using `document.querySelector('text.circle-chart__percent')`.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it's usually better to add some explanation. What have you done to solve the problem? Code-only answers tend to not be useful to other readers, and therefore attract downvotes. See [How to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @JessedeBruijne Instead of explaining very simple terms, I thought to skip.

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what you mean, but if you want to add the attribute "stroke-dasharry" to the text tag with classname "circle-chart__percent", then down here is the solution in plain javascript, which you can add to you webpage.

```
<script>

function transfer() {
  var src = document.getElementsByClassName("circle-chart__circle")[0],
      trgt = document.getElementsByClassName("circle-chart__percent")[0];
  trgt.setAttribute("stroke-dasharray",src.getAttribute("stroke-dasharray"));
}
transfer();    

</script>
```

I created the function transfer inside a script tag, which can be added to the end of your page just before the  tag. Inside that function I searched for the tag with the classname "circle-chart__circle" and stored it's reference in the variable src. Than I did the same for the tag with classname "circle-chart__percent" and stored it's reference in trgt. Next I added the attibute "stroke-dasharray" to the tag referenced by trgt.

To complete the process I called transfer.